# IBM MobileFirst Hybrid App Client Side server settings

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am using the IBM MobileFirst Studio version 7.1. I have written an HTTP adapter than can access the temperature converter web-service provided by w3schools [Link to WSDL](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx).

The application can connect and retrieve the results without any issue when previewing as common resources. I want to test this on an Android device. I find that after adding the Android environment, I have to manually change the "wlServerHost" property in the generated AndroidProject's /assets/wlclient.properties everytime I want to deploy it to the physical device. i.e, it keeps getting re-generated every time a build is done

How can I correctly set the server IP address so that the app can communicate with the server? Do I edit the worklight.properties file under server/conf and set the publicWorkLightHostname to my server IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it gets regenerated is fine. The problem seems to be with the value put there (which you did not mention...). The value is determined by the default in your workstation...

Either way, you can change this by going to Run as -> Build settings and remote target. Set a valid to the correct IP, port and your project name and that info will find itself in the wlclient.properties files during build.

I would check, though, why your host is what you see there...

Comment: @IanAdar. What was essentially getting populated was the pc-name. I am testing on a home network and wanted to supply an IP and wanted a place to set that correctly.